# Outlook Add - Update TaskPane Elements on OnMessageRecipientsChanged event

Tags: javascript, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, customtaskpane

I am trying to update TaskPane HTML elements upon event OnMessageRecipientsChanged gets fired. The event is received successfully however, I am unable to access HTML elements using:

```
document.getElementById("item-subject").innerHTML = "Testing..."
```

Also, this element is available in Office.OnReady() and I am able to update it there but I instead want to do this onMessageRecipientsChanged event.

**This works:**

```
Office.onReady(function () {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    document.getElementById("item-subject").innerHTML = "Testing...";
  });
});
```

**This doesn't work:**

```
function onMessageRecipientsChangedHandler(event) {
  document.getElementById("item-subject").innerHTML = "Testing...";
}
```

How can I get this to work?

Comment: I could not reproduce this issue on Windows Desktop Outlook or Outlook Web (don't have a Mac to try Mac Outlook). Which client are you seeing this issue on? I am not seeing any code where you are registering your handler with addHandlerAsync method, is that what you're missing by any chance:

Office.context.mailbox.item.addHandlerAsync(
            Office.EventType.RecipientsChanged,
            onMessageRecipientsChangedHandler,
            function (result) {
              // ...
            });

Comment: Thank you @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT! I had hooked up event as below:

`Office.actions.associate("onMessageRecipientsChangedHandler", onMessageRecipientsChangedHandler);`

I tried your approach too but now I am getting a different error:

`Office.initialize = function () {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(
      Office.EventType.RecipientsChanged,
      onMessageRecipientsChangedHandler,
      function (result) {...}
    );
  });
};`

**Error:**
Uncaught Error Function addHandlerAsync has invalid parameters.

Comment: Which client (Outlook on Windows, Mac, Web, ..) and version are you using? Is there any chance for you to share the [minimal] code that demonstrates the issue as a snippet in ScriptLab add-in that you can find in Outlook Add-ins store?

Comment: Please find more details:
**Windows 11 Microsoft® Outlook® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2111 Build 16.0.14701.20278) 64-bit**

`Office.Ready((info)  = function () {
  $(document).ready(function () {
    Office.context.mailbox.addHandlerAsync(
      Office.EventType.RecipientsChanged,
      onMessageRecipientsChangedHandler,
      function (result) {
          Office.context.document.getElementById("item-subject").innerHTML = "Updated...";
        }
      }
    );
  });
});`

Above code is part of an plugin named **launchevent.js** registered under **webpack.config.js**

Comment: Just to add to that I don't have access to Script Lab for Outlook due to organizational policies but I'll give it a go on my personal laptop